# Can I distribute\install a copy of the UWP project to a different Windows 10 desktop system?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, uwp, xamarin.forms

VS 2015, Xamarin Forms, PCL. 
I can attach my Android phone by cable, and install to it. I can run "Local Machine" on my windows 10 development machine and test there. I want to give a copy of the UWP project to someone else to test with (on Windows 10 desktop). This is a new application, not in any stores, so...how to do this? Can it be done without using store distribution, and if so, can someone tell me how to do this, or point me to a link that documents this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create package (like for publishing to store) and then with `PowerShell` install it on another PC. [Packaging UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the distribution of an app to only a certain group of testers, without first publishing a submission that's broadly available, you can use the same app submission process as any app you submit. To allow only certain people to get the app free of charge, and prevent other customers from seeing its listing or downloading it - read more about [Beta testing and targeted distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution)